# What is the correct way to construct a databricks custom container such that I can install a custom jar?

Tags: scala, containers, databricks

So I'm looking to deliver a custom docker image for our databricks cluster to run on. I tried looking through the examples and documentation on Databrick's website as well as the github (here: https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/custom-containers.html and here: https://github.com/databricks/containers) but was unable to determine where to drop off a custom jar within the container such that it was recognized by the cluster.

All my current custom container is doing is the following

```
FROM databricksruntime/standard:latest

COPY target/scala-2.11/some.artifact.jar /container-jars/some.artifact.jar
```

I've also tried copying the jar to the `dbfs` folder in databricks in hope of then using the install method in the UI to no avail. However it seems the `/dbfs/` != `dbfs:/` so that didn't work

Any ideas would be super helpful. Thanks!